# Looping days with specific outputs - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Need a hand with this code. I want the temperatures to loop with the days its designated to, Monday = 24 degrees etc, but the problem is that when I output, it loops all the days of the week to one degree output.

```
import java.io.*;

class Scen2_Mod3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    PrintWriter prnt = new PrintWriter("Beach.txt"); 
    //prompt user of program
    System.out.println("FAHRENHEIT TEMPERATURE FOR THE WEEK VS CELCIUS CONVERSION IN ASCENDING ORDER");
    //set array
    String[] days = new String[]{"Monday", "Tuesday" , "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    int[] temps = {50,53,78,51,52,88};
    //quick declaration of temps.length to help with efficiency
    int size = temps.length;

    //intoduce the for loop to find the minimum
      for (int i = 0 ;i< size-1; i++){
         int min = i;
    //bring in nested for loop with j, to see if the value in the array is less than minimum previously stated
         for (int j = i+1; j<size; j++){
            if (temps[j] < temps[min]){
            min = j;
            }
         }
         //hold a temporary value to equal itself to sort the array
         int t = temps[min];
         temps[min] = temps[i];
         temps[i] = t;
      }
      //set a for loop to go through the now sorted array to produce an output
      prnt.println("These are the days Sam can go to the beach! 24 degrees celcius or higher! ");
      for (int j = 0;j < days.length;j++ )
          {
      for (int i = 0;i < size ;i++ )
      {
          System.out.print("On " + days[j] + " the temperature was " + temps[i] + " fahrenheit " + "\t");
          System.out.print("----->\t");
          int totalTemp = (temps[i] - 32) * 5/9;
          System.out.println("On " + days[j] + " the temperature was " + totalTemp + " celcius " + "\n");
          if (totalTemp >= 24)
          {
              prnt.println(days[j] + totalTemp);
          }
          
      }
      }
      prnt.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem statement is quite unclear, please clarify what the issue is.

Comment: I'm more referring to the last block of code, which outputs the result. Right now it is outputting every day of the week Monday,Tuesday etc to one temperature conversion instead of just one. So right now its going... eg; Monday = 24, Tuesday = 24 instead of Monday = 24, Tuesday = 26

Comment: Number of days are 7, size of temps is 6. If you correct this then you can use single for loop, you can get day[ i] and it's temps[i]

Comment: Does temp array contain respective temperatures for the days? If yes, then there are only 6 elements in temp array whereas there are 7 days. If you want to sort the arrays according to temp, you can use TreeMap and put your data, it will automatically sort the data. PS. put temp as keys in TreeMap.

Comment: Thanks guys, didn't even notice the sizes of temps haha. Appreciate it :)